# Not able to pass the parameters to SQL view in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sql-view

I created a sqlview(`villagefilter_view`) in GeoServer and added one parameter `%vilselected%`

```
select * from niphad_survey where village=%vilselected%
```

Name: `vilselected`
Default value: `'Ranwad'`
Validation regular expression: `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`

I tried to pass the parameter from a selec option onchange value with vilSelectForView name.

Following is my code to genarate request url from GeoServer

```
var niphadSurveyVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        loader: function(extent) {
            $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/postgis_22_sample/wfs', {
                type: 'GET',
                data:{
                    service: 'WFS',
                    version: '1.1.0',
                    request: 'GetFeature',                  
                    typename: 'villagefilter_view',
                    viewparams: "vilselected:"+vilSelectForView,
                    srsname: 'EPSG:3857',                   
                    bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
                }
            }).done(function(response) {

         niphadSurveyVectorSource.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
            });
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
        projection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
```

After page lode the default parameter data is loading on map but onchange my select option the parameter is not passing to request URL.

How can I load the dynamic view data on map by onchange with the village name?

Comment: what value are you trying to send? please look in the debugger and check the url being sent and add it to the question, then look in the GeoServer log file and see if there is an error there

Comment: The request url: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/postgis_22_sample/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=villagefilter_view&srsname=EPSG%3A3857&viewparams=vilselected%3AWelapur&bbox=8198826.746438718%2C2261465.9188452247%2C8317227.703252456%2C2304117.780628353%2CEPSG%3A3857

Comment: Error is: <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException java.io.IOExceptionERROR: column "welapur" does not exist Position: 94
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>

Comment: it seems that your table has changed and has lost a column

Comment: @IanTurton did you solve this?

Comment: @AN10 - there was nothing for me to solve

Comment: you could pass a string parameter in the url?